# fatal error - error building POM (may not be this project's POM)

Tags: java, maven, nexus

```
Project ID: com.abc.def.MyProject:pom:null

Reason: Cannot find parent: com.xyz.list.MyWonderfulFamilly for project   com.abc.def.MyProject:pom:null for  com.abc.def.MyProject:pom:null

[INFO] TRACE
org.apache.maven.reactor.MavenExecutionException: Cannot find parent: com.xyz.list.MyWonderfulFamilly for project  com.abc.def.MyProject:pom:null for  com.abc.def.MyProject:pom:null

Caused by org.apache.maven.project.ProjectBuildingException: POM 'com.xyz.list.MyWonderfulFamilly' not found in repository: Unable to download the artifact from the repository

           com:xyz:list:MyWonderfulFamilly:pom     

from the specified remote repositories:
    CompanyName.Pricing.G7 (http://mksrvsub01.domain.xxxxxx)

for project com.xyz.list.MyWonderfulFamilly at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.findModelFromRepository(DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.java:1392)

Caused by: org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.ArtifactNotFoundException: Unable to download the artifact from any repository

               com:xyz:list:MyWonderfulFamilly:pom

from the specified remote repositories:
    CompanyName.Pricing.G7 (http://mksrvsub01.domain.xxxxxx)
```

1. I have tried `mvn clean install` on the project directory, and also at the project root - same error
2. I have tried deleting all `lastUpdated` files in the `.m2` repository - same error
3. Deleted files in the `~.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\plugins` - same error
4. Deleted all project files and folders and created new directory and checked out project files and run `mvn clean install` - same error

Apache Maven 2.2.1 r801777
Win XP, x86, 32-bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quote:

> Caused by Unable to download the artifact from any repository
>
> com:xyz:list:MyWonderfulFamilly:pom
>
> from the specified remote repositories:
>
> CompanyName.Pricing.G7

Did you check that you can access the repository? Is the pom/artifact available in the repository? If so, check the local `~./m2/com/xyz/list` folder if the artifact or an error message is there. Delete and re-try if required.

Comment: yes i can access my repository on my browser. can i download the `pom` and `sha1` from the browser and put them in the folder in `.m2/repository/etc`?

Comment: i did the above, and i made sure that the pom and sha files are in the m2 repository. but when i import the projects into eclipse. build error: non-resolvable parent POM occurs

Comment: as long as maven is not offline it tries to check/download artifacts from the server. where do you download the pom file from? Do you need to enter credentials before you are able to download these files?

Comment: what i did was to point the browser to the url given in the stacktrace of the fatal error. and i didnt have to enter any credentials when downloading the pom file from the browser

Comment: can you run mvn offline with the pom in the local repository? will the error occur in that case?

Comment: i ran `mvn -o install` and i still get the same error building POM; reason: cannot find parent : com.xyz.list.MyWonderfulFamilly

Comment: any chance that the pom is invalid (ie referring to modules/parent) that are not available?

Answer (score 0):

i realized that i have to add more dependent maven projects to the build path, and do mvn clean install and after a laborious 2 hours the thing is fixed!

Answer (score 0):

In some cases (my case in particular) some additional security tweaks might be involved.

What I mean is that if you work with a central repository that available through a certificate, you might have to check if your 
**JAVA_HOME\jre\lib\security\cacerts** file stores the certificate in question.
In my case after importing the certificate file in there (I used the KeyStore Explorer application, but it can be done on the command line either) and all my processes continued normally.

Comment: Weirdly, the problem might be different, but the error message is the same.